# mysql Cumulative sum for each unique ID in each sale:

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-8.0

I have trouble adding and accumulating my amounts per id,
I use this solution but it doesn't work and it adds up all the ids,

```
id     product_id  quantity  acumulado
168    190         1         1
169    190         3         4
170    195         1         5
171    190         25.60     30.60
172    190         1         31.60
```

I use this:

```
SET @csum := 0;

UPDATE sma_sale_items
   SET acumulado = (@csum := @csum + quantity)
 ORDER BY id, product_id;
```

any solution? ineed this

```
id     product_id  quantity  acumulado
168    190         1         1
169    190         3         4
170    195         1         1
171    190         25.60     29.60
172    190         1         30.60
```

For version 5.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT` statement containing window analytic function instead of an `UPDATE` statement :

```
SELECT id, product_id, quantity, SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS acumulado
  FROM sma_sale_items
```

`acumulado` column shouldn't need to be stored within a table being a computable column.

<kbd>[Demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28aa6da0284d749dcfa87c7134fe91b6)</kbd>

If you still prefer `UPDATE`, then use :

```
UPDATE sma_sale_items s1
 JOIN (
      SELECT id, product_id, SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS acumulado
        FROM sma_sale_items
       ORDER BY id
      ) s2 ON s1.ID=s2.ID
  SET s1.acumulado = s2.acumulado;
```

<kbd>[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1ae349617ce7358fcef40fb915ee93c)</kbd>

**UPDATE** : Depending on the last edit consider using

> `SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY id) AS acumulado`
>
> **instead of** `SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS acumulado`

by adding `PARTITION BY product_id` in order to distinguish the sums grouped by `product_id`

<kbd>[Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93f00a1dbf9f5070edcd08cd3568dc67)</kbd>

Comment: thanks, it happens that the id 195 should not be added with the id 190, they must be sums for each id

Comment: welcome @KevinGomez , but were you able to look at your acumulado values vs. those within the demo ?